# How I connect my solar panels with a solar inverter?

Tags: inverter

I have six solar panels with a voltage of 37.4V, with 17.39A and seven solar panels of voltage 42.8V with  11.69A. My solar inverter supports a maximum voltage of 500V and maximum current 100A. I just want to know how to connect these solar panels in way that generates the voltage and current supported by the inverter with maximum efficiency.

Comment: What does the datasheet/installation insturction say? Are you using an MPPT?

Comment: yes its MPPT with Max PV input 500VDC, and IMax 100A, also its a 6KW invertor of model Fronus Infineon Plus 6kw.

Comment: That will be a difficult match. Sell one type and buy more identical to the first one? Or get either two inverters or an inverter which has two separate inputs?

Comment: Use an inverter that takes 2 separate strings of cells.